Can't use Text Composable in Button of Jetpack Compose
I'm new to Jetpack Compose. I follow tutorial from docs. But unfortunately, I can't use following code.
Button(onClick = {

        }) {
            Text(text = "Hello")
        }

error is
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function.
. .
I tried every possible ways to fix that error. Thanks for your time.
I've already tried every code snippets from docs but nothing is working.

The code looks fine. Can you provide a full composable function that contains this code and reproduces the problem? Please also add the import statements.

https://github.com/thawdezin/my_application Here's my repo for the code.

Please put all relevant code in the question itself. Links to code on external sites are problematic as explained in [ask]. Make sure the code you post here qualifies as a [mre].

I found the solution. Simply disable the K2 Kotlin mode in the settings. 
